# Dependencies within count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

So, I'm trying to automate peering of multiple VPCs together into a hub-and-spoke architecture. I've got my hub VPC and a list of spoke VPCs. Peering itself is easy:

```
resource "google_compute_network_peering" "hub_to_spoke" {
  count          = length(var.spokes)

  name           = "peer-hub-to-spoke${count.index}"
  network        = var.hub
  peer_network   = var.spokes[count.index]
}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "spoke_to_hub" {
  count          = length(var.spokes)

  name           = "peer-spoke-to-hub${count.index}"
  network        = var.spokes[count.index]
  peer_network   = var.hub
}
```

[EDIT] with variables like below (in reality I pull them from data, but let's keep things simple):

```
spokes = [
  "projects/my-project/global/networks/vpc-spoke1",
  "projects/my-project/global/networks/vpc-spoke2",
  "projects/my-project/global/networks/vpc-spoke3"
]
hub = "projects/my-project/global/networks/vpc-hub"
```

Now, in GCP you cannot run multiple routing-related operations at the same time and each of these peerings does touch routing in hub VPC. For a single spoke I can deal with it by adding explicit dependency to spoke_to_hub:

```
depends_on = [
  google_compute_network_peering.hub_to_spoke
]
```

but... how do I make a counted resource to create only **one peering instance at a time**?

PS. yes I know I can use for_each here, but it's a trimmed down copy of a code with a bit more complex data structures so let's skip it.

Comment: These two need to communicate with each other?

Comment: It's not the best solution but if you can't figure out how do it with dependencies you can use the `-parallelism=n ` flag when you launch  `terraform apply ` command, setting n at 1. In this way Terraform create one resource at time. https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply#parallelism-n

Comment: Can you give us an example for `var.spokes`?

Comment: @MarkoE - these two are the two sides of the same peering

Comment: parallelism=n is close to what I'm looking for, but if it affected only a single resource instead of the whole config...

@Sebastian - added sample vars to the description

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in Terraform are between `resource` blocks, and not between individual instances declared by them. This is because the repetition arguments (`count` and `for_each`) also have dependencies. For example, you could've expressed the dependency you added by adding a reference into the second resource's `count` argument, rather than using `depends_on`:

```
  count = length(google_compute_network_peering.hub_to_spoke)
```

With that said: if you need to define a specific order for these individual objects to be created or updated then you will need to declare it as multiple separate resources, each with its own dependencies. Terraform will then respect those dependencies and create the objects in the order you designated.

Terraform assumes that multiple instances of the same resource are always independent of one another and so it will create them all concurrently whenever possible. Declaring separate resources with dependencies between them is how we explain to Terraform the correct order in which to create different objects.

Comment: The problem is - the module doesn't know upfront how many VPCs there is. So instead of explicitly adding each to the code, I'd rather have them provided as a list in variables.

Comment: Since dependencies are something Terraform needs to know before doing any expression evaluation (including variables), I can't think of any way to meet that requirement using Terraform today. Anything involving dependencies between objects must always be defined statically, so that Terraform can compute the dependency graph before beginning expression evaluation.

Comment: If this restriction is that the remote system only allows for creating one "peering" per network at a time, it might be interesting to discuss this problem in the issue tracker for this provider to see if the provider team would be able to introduce some provider-side mutexes to effectively serialize these in the same way the remote system requires, since the provider can rely on knowledge about the remote system that Terraform Core cannot.

Comment: (In that case, from Terraform Core's perspective it would still be asking the provider to create many at once, but the provider itself would choose to handle them sequentially in order to meet the remote API's additional constraints.)